# Firebird - Foreign key reference target does not exist

Tags: firebird

I did a database backup and then I am trying to do a restore now but I got this error when I do the restore

```
gbak: ERROR:violation of FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_WINDOW_4" on table "WINDOW" 
gbak: ERROR:    Foreign key reference target does not exist 
gbak: ERROR:    Problematic key value is ("QUOTE_ID" = 107)
```

I checked and I found the target ID `QUOTE_ID = 107` already exists so why I get this error or where I should look at ?

Answer (score 1):

There was a previous error precede this one, about a field was set as `not null` and there was some records has this field as null so when I fixed this error and tried again to do backup and restore I did not get any more errors.